# How to build yaml-cpp with CMake on Windows?

Tags: cmake, yaml

I can be a real dummy when it comes to following instructions sometimes, pardon me. I'm in a bit of a hurry to get YAML files working with my program. I have downloaded the YAML files from the official site, I have downloaded an installed the latest CMake. What do i do now? I don't understand DLL creation nor the issues that there seem to be.

When I open CMake I put in the path to the extracted yaml-cpp-0.2.7 folder with the yaml-cpp.pc.cmake file and I set up the build path. Is there anything else I should do here? I get this error:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to ""Visual Studio 9 2008"".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/path/yaml-cpp-0.2.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/path/yaml-cpp-0.2.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
```

Also once i'm done with this what should I do next to be able to launch the example code from the site? Which configuration should I use to be able to launch the file on VS Express 2010? I'm stuck, I can't find answers anywhere.

Comment: Looks like broken CMake installation. Do you use GUI or command line CMake tool? What generator are you choosing when configuring your build?

Comment: anyone please can give full answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a mistake here, i tried to get the CMake file going on a computer which didn't have the IDE installed, i installed VC++ 2010 and it works now.

I loaded the yaml-cpp solution into VC++ 2010, bulit it, linked everything and it works fine now.